# How to redirect back two pages Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a book page. On this page is the button "In favorite". If the user clicks on the button and is authenticated, it will use **addBookmark** view to add a new object into the database(and just reload the book page). However, if the user isn't authenticated, it'll redirect to the login page firstly.

```
@login_required
def addBookmark(request, slug):
book = Book.objects.get(slug=slug)
if BookMark.objects.filter(user=request.user, book=book).exists():
    bookMark = BookMark.objects.get(user=request.user, book=book)
    bookMark.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER")) 

newBookMark = BookMark.objects.create(user=request.user, book=book)
newBookMark.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

**The problem:** When a user is redirected to the login page, the next URL will just add a new object in db and reload the page, but this is the login page. How can I redirect users back to the book page if the user isn't authenticated firstly?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove `@login_required`.

You can redirect user manually like this:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
   return redirect("bookmark_url")
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. My bookmark_url just add an object into db and refresh page. First of all, I have to check whether a user is authenticated.
If it is, I'll use the view above and refresh a book page.
If it isn't, I have to redirect to 'login' view, after authentication I need to call 'addBookmark' view, it'll add an object in the database and then I need to redirect user back to the book page(instead of just reload page)